# Insert data in a table variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert data in a table variable. Code is attached.

```
DECLARE @TEST_TABLE TABLE
(
    NAME_       VARCHAR(200)    NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO @TEST_TABLE
VALUES 'TEST_STRING'
```

However, it shows the following error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
>   Incorrect syntax near 'TEST_STRING'.

Can anyone please provide insights on this?

Answer (score 6):

You're missing braces:

```
DECLARE @TEST_TABLE TABLE
(
    NAME_       VARCHAR(200)    NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO @TEST_TABLE
VALUES ('TEST_STRING')
```

Comment: @Paul I do :) Although obviously I'm delegating as much "raw" SQL to O/RM as possible...

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
DECLARE @TEST_TABLE TABLE
(
    NAME_       VARCHAR(200)    NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO @TEST_TABLE
VALUES 
(
(SELECT 'TEST_STRING')
)
```

**(Or)**

```
DECLARE @TEST_TABLE TABLE
(
    NAME_       VARCHAR(200)    NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO @TEST_TABLE
VALUES ('TEST_STRING')
```